# $x\le\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil\left\lceil\frac{x}{\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil}\right\rceil$?

Tags: inequality

$x\le\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil\left\lceil\frac{x}{\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil}\right\rceil$

How do I show this?

I made a plot, and it looks true:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** $\frac{x}{\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil} \leq \lceil\frac{x}{\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil}\rceil$.

Comment: I of course assume that you're only considering $x \gt 0$.

Answer (score 7):

Divide both sides by $\lceil \sqrt x\rceil$.